# Displaying Dandelin spheres touching hyperbola boundary patches in cone

Tags: graphics3d, geometry

Can we show the [Dandelin spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833973/prove-that-the-directrix-focus-and-focus-focus-definitions-are-equivalent) scenario (shown by user [Hrhm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/332390/hrhm) for case of ellipse) for a hyperbola as well? I'm not happy with what we get to see of this on the net.

The double nappe/sheet of a cone is cut by a plane inclined at angle $ \beta < 2 \alpha $ ( cutting plane inclination to a generator of cone, cone vertex angle ) cutting both nappes with hyperbolas as intersecting arcs.

The Dandelin spheres are placed in each cone tangentially, [foci *outside*  directrix planes](http://www.clowder.net/hop/Dandelin/ellhyp.gif) The cutting plane contacts spheres at foci so that focal distance *difference* from hyperbola is constant.

I can also do this using `ContourPlot3D`, however you can make it with a great image quality.

Proper choice of $\alpha, \beta$ so that the difference of line segments can be convincingly visualized.

EDIT 1:

Some changes from the following need to be made to see  points of tangential contact and radius vectors in the plane at an arbitrary point on hyperbola.

```
{s1=5,s2=3,H=-1,al=.8,bt=-2,Z=11.5,PltLim=5.1};
snal=(s1+s2)/Z;al=ArcSin[snal];tnal=Tan[al];
S1=ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2+(z+s1/snal)^2==s1^2,{x,-PltLim,PltLim},{y,-PltLim,PltLim},{z,-PltLim,PltLim}];
S2=ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2+(z-s2/snal)^2==s2^2,{x,-PltLim,PltLim},{y,-PltLim,PltLim},{z,-PltLim,PltLim}];
Keg=ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2 -z^2 tnal^2==0,{x,-PltLim,PltLim},{y,-PltLim,PltLim},{z,-PltLim,PltLim},ContourStyle-> Opacity[.35]];
Plne=ContourPlot3D[ z  ==-x Tan[bt]+ H,{x,-PltLim,PltLim},{y,-PltLim,PltLim},{z,-PltLim,PltLim},ContourStyle-> Opacity[.9]];
Show[{S1,S2,Keg,Plne},PlotRange->All, Boxed->False,Axes->None]
```

[image: my attempt]

Comment: Since you can do this with `ContourPlot`, please include the code and its output. I have a hard time following your description.

Comment: Above is a start putting them together.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a starting point. Figuring out what I exactly did is left as an exercise.

```
With[{r = 5/2, φ = π/4, s1 = 3/4, s2 = 3/2},
     Graphics3D[{{Directive[CapForm[None], Opacity[2/3]],
                  Tube[{{0, 0, -r Cot[φ/2]}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, r Cot[φ/2]}}, {r, 0, r}]},
                 {Sphere[{0, 0, s1 Csc[φ/2]}, s1], Sphere[{0, 0, -s2 Csc[φ/2]}, s2]},
                 {Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity[1/2, LightBlue]],
                  InfinitePlane[#1, {#2 - #1, {0, 1, 0}}] &[
                  {s1/(s1 + s2) Sqrt[(s1 + s2)^2 - (s1 - s2)^2 Sin[φ/2]^2], 0,
                   s1 Csc[φ/2] - s1 (s1 - s2) Sin[φ/2]/(s1 + s2)},
                  {s2/(s1 + s2) Sqrt[(s1 + s2)^2 - (s1 - s2)^2 Sin[φ/2]^2], 0,
                   s2 (s2 - s1) Sin[φ/2]/(s1 + s2) - s2 Csc[φ/2]}]}},
                Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: Dandelin spheres, hyperbolic case]

Comment: Here are the corresponding pictures for the other conics: [ellipse](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MMbK4.png), [parabola](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gCV7n.png). The [old code by Stan Wagon](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=vpYmj7ohofsC&pg=PA193) was rather long, but thanks to primitives like `Cone[]`, `Sphere[]`, and `InfinitePlane[]` being built-in, things are now easier to do.

Comment: We need to show (with a small disk or tiny sphere) points of 1) tangential contact , 2) arbitrary point on hyperbola , 3) parallel circle points joined at any arbitrary point so that the difference of segment lengths is seen constant for hyperbola.

Comment: As noted, this is only a starting point. If you'll read the code carefully, you will see that I've already found the tangency points for you. The others should not be too hard to add, if you're sufficiently inclined.

Comment: OK, I'll take this hint.

Comment: @J.M.'slackofA.I. Can you show the code to get ellipse and parabola?

Answer (score 1):

Why not go to the WRI demo site and search for demos involving the Dandelin spheres? You can download the source code and see how some others did it.

For example: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DandelinSpheresForAnEllipse/

Comment: I believe the OP wanted the "hyperbolic" case of the Dandelin spheres, unlike the "elliptic case" featured in your book and the demonstration you linked to. (But he certainly can adapt the constructions in those to this one.)

Comment: @stan wagon Pleasure going through many interesting Mathematica coded geometrical realizations in your book. May be you would also include hyperbola intersection made by plane touching Dandilion spheres in next edition.